# Why i get compilation error in C# with generic

Tags: c#, generics

I have method that contain parameter `BlockingCollection<T>` queue, and T must extend my class QueueItem (it's work fine without the generic).

```
private void ProcessQueue<T>(BlockingCollection<T> queue) where T: QueueItem
{
     QueueItem frame;
     while (true)
     {
          if (queue.TryTake(out frame, -1))
          {
              frame.execute();
          }
     }
}
```

The compilation error on `if (queue.TryTake(out frame, -1))` : "the method has some invalid arguments

Why?

Edit the method definition is:

```
BlockingCollection<T> TryTake(T, Int32)
```

Comment: What's the definition of `TryTake`?

Comment: @king.code https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287154(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`frame` should be a `T` but you are providing a `QueueItem`. Change the type of `frame`:

```
 T frame;
 while (true)
 {
      if (queue.TryTake(out frame, -1))
      {
          frame.execute();
      }
 }
```